# Destructuring an object into another object

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I am trying to update my code to es6.
I updated all my other code to es6 syntax except this part.
I understand the main concept of destructuring (maybe?),
but I don't know how to do destructuring on this code (`const userData` part).
I'd like to make this code cleaner.

```
$scope.doRegister = (registerForm) => {
  const userData = {
    emailAddress: $scope.registerData.email,
    password: $scope.registerData.password,
    firstName: $scope.registerData.first,
    lastName: $scope.registerData.last
  };
  userService.registerUser(userData)
  .then((userData) => {
    $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({ historyRoot: true });
    $state.go('app.deviceSetup');
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
  });
}
```

Comment: What is you're trying to accomplish with destructuring?  We need to know what you want to do with it.

Comment: make code more cleaner and update code from es5 to es6 mainly. I updated other part but somewhat I have difficulty time to understand and use destructuring.  I'd like to use destructuring feature on const userData part

Comment: Please add that info to your question so people reading the question have a better idea for what you're trying to do.  You already have one close vote for "Unclear what you're asking" (not from me) so your question needs to be made much clearer.

Comment: THanks jfriend00! I edited my post words. I don't know it's enough to understand...I am a junior dev still learning so anything if you can point or help would be great !!

Comment: So... you want to use destructuring to change the names of properties of an object.

Comment: I've suggested an edit to the post that changes the title. Please accept it if that is indeed what you are trying to do; otherwise, you can reject it.

Comment: First of all thanks brian! And ..Umm..my assignment change any feature that can be updated to es6. And I got comment on const userData part to restructuring. And I had no idea how to apply it on this code. I try to change my title now

Comment: @moniqueyj You might have an assignment to change everything to es6, but if you ask a question here it has to be something more specific. Otherwise, it might be closed as too broad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are essentially trying to "destructure" `$scope.registerData` into a new object, `userData`. But destructuring only supports destructuring into **variables**, not objects. Therefore, you could write:

```
const {
  email:    emailAddress, 
  password, 
  first:    firstName, 
  last:     lastName
} = $scope.registerData;

const userData = {emailAddress, password, firstName, lastName};
```

The first line above is destructuring; the second line uses "shorthand property notation" to build the new object.

There have been proposals, and many questions here on SO, about how to destructure into a new object, but there is no easy, obvious way to do it. The closest you can come is probably using [object rest syntax](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread), which will work only if you know what properties you want to omit, will not allow renaming, will create extra variables `dontNeed1` etc., and may or may not have native browser support.

```
const {...userData, dontNeed1, dontNeed2} = ...$scope.registerData;
```

It is certainly a viable option in this case, or perhaps even preferable, not to try to use destructuring at all, and/or to use @BrianMcCutchon's approach.

Comment: Thanks Torazaburo! this helps me a lot since I wanted to see the changed way no matter what it is the best way or not also. and thanks for your opinion and explanation. I am going to try to apply your code now. and see what happen and on my whole code too. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I don't think destructuring is the right way to do this. However, there are other ways you can clean up this code. The simplest is to save `$scope.registerData` to a temporary variable:

```
const rd = $scope.registerData
const userData = {
  emailAddress: rd.email,
  password: rd.password,
  firstName: rd.first,
  lastName: rd.last
};
```

Don't get me wrong, you *could* use destructuring, but you'd end up having to duplicate field names somewhere. This is cleaner.

Comment: I totally understand what u suggested. But I have to apply destucturing here. Sorry I made you confuse. But thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: @moniqueyj I don't think you "have" to change it. Was this a suggestion in a code review? If so, you can respond with, "Destructuring doesn't work well here because..." and include the reasons mentioned in torazaburo's answer. You could even respond with a link to this thread.

Comment: Awsome. Thanks Brian for all your help and comments. everything that you did for helping me is treasure for me! Have a good night :)